# How to improve specific aspect of teamwork? (Confirmation of receipt of information)

Tags: teamwork

Let's say I work in a team which works very well together in almost all aspects. If I had to pick one thing where the team underperforms, it's when it comes to acknowledging that information is received.

If I wanted to improve this aspect, how would I go about it?

I have tried:

- Outright asking for it (was dismissed as unnecessary)
- Leading by example (saw very little change from that)

In a comment I got the question what problem this causes. The problem is that there are three options:

- I have received it and will get back to you later,
- I have received it but forgotten about it and would like a reminder, and
- I have received it but don't have an opinion/would not like to take further action on it.

These three call for different responses from me. I could assume one and then be corrected later, but that seems unnecessary for all of us.

Comment: What actual problem is it causing you that people don't acknowledge the receipt of the information? So long as they _do_ receive it, that seems to be okay to me.

Comment: Use something like Asana.

Comment: Some email systems have the confirmation or receipt option as follow: After the recipients open the emails, the system automatically sends the receipts to the senders. This may work for some daily information among the team.  However, if the information is super important, then you call for a  team meeting, and after the meeting you send out the summary of the meeting to all attendees to confirm that this is what everyone agrees on.

Comment: Hard problem to solve. If you make it a requirement or even an informal expectation, they'll just send the receipt without ever reading your doc. Or even a long email. Most people simply don't read past the first half page, unless they absolutely need to fish out a specific piece of information.

Answer (score 3):

Why do your team members have to acknowledge that the information was received? Are your team members very forgetful or do you frequently have bad connections that cause messages or other information to not be sent?

If you are not in a management position the best you can do is pester your team members asking them if they have received the information but it's going to lead to diminishing returns as they get more annoyed by the confirmation prompts.

If this is really a problem that needs to be solved, and by that I mean it causes a real negative impact on the team's work and not just because it bothers you, it has to be solved with structure. You have to get your manager or someone with authority to make it mandatory and there has to be repercussions for not complying.

You can also try to use some form of project management software to help with reminders and tracking who does and does not do it but the requirement still has to be brought forward by someone with the authority to do so.

Answer (score 3):

*Problem 1*:

> I have received it and will get back to you later,

So make a note to get back later to them and followup.

*Problem 2*:

> I have received it but forgotten about it and would like a reminder,

The other party too can be forgetful.

*Problem 2*:

> I have received it but don't have an opinion/would not like to take further action on it.

Again, make a note to follow it up with them. Or not.

The point I am trying to make here is:

1. You seem to have a specific idea of how things should work.
2. You want others to conform to your way of working.
3. No one else has a complain about how things are done currently.

Do you see the problem?

Your expectations are **unrealistic** - *Why should other colleagues conform to your way of thinking and working style?* When you can't change other people's behavior, it is only reasonable to change your expectations from them, and adjust your behaviour towards them accordingly.

(Note that if you are the boss, it is not that unreasonable to expect the team to follow a workflow that makes your job easier. But if you are the boss, then the nature of your questions also changes, and the answers here will be different.)

Answer (score -2):

Send the info with a little bit missing - then they come back to you.

That’s the confirmation done.

Comment: So if they add the mail to a personal backlog they have to interrupt their workflow to ask for the missing information? Possibly pushing the task again to the bottom of the backlog or creating unnessary synchronous information exchanges just for the purpose of them checking with you? I doubt that this helps the process as a whole.

Comment: No answer is in my opinion better than this approach. I do not have a definitive answer. Hence, I did not reply with an answer.

Comment: It's a creative solution for special cases, but probably not something to teach people to do regularly.

Comment: And they don't confirm when you provide the missing piece? Or do you only supply part of the missing piece so they come back to you again?